# Looking for an old sci-fi book about an old space station

Tags: story-identification, books

Hi I'm looking for an old scifi book that I read back in the 70s
There is a space station  in our solar system built by people who 
left to explore the universe long ago. The people living aboard it 
now are much less advanced. A stranger shows up who knows things about 
the station that no one else does. Turns out he is from the people 
who built it and they want it back to go explore other universes. 
I think it was old when I read it. Thank you for any help.

I remember that he could get to parts of the space station that 
the people living there could not. It was a paperback  I think 
there was a picture of a space station on the cover. I'm pretty 
sure it was not an Ace double book. Not much to go on I'm afraid 
Stand alone book  not series  printed in US The people living on 
it know very little about the people who built it they have 
space travel but don't like to explore.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Some of the things that you describe make me think about Frederik Pohl's Gateway, but probably this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Ihank you for the idea  but this book came out years before Gateway.